# declaration/initialization issue with multiple files in C++

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, header-files

I know how to call a simple function (i.e. `add(int x, int y){return x+y;}` and nothing more) from a second .cpp file. 
Now I wanted to go one step further and get following problem:
in my main.cpp I got one line like this (important part is the variable **a_wt** at the end):

```
transform(a_att.begin(), a_att.end(), a_att.begin(), std::bind1st(std::multiplies<float>(), a_wt));
```

so, but now I got a 2nd .cpp file where I've put a huge block of repetitive code asking for input in a void function. (u can imagine sth like "apple_prize?" cin >> ... "cherry_prize?" cin >> ...
It is so long that I wanted to put this block in an extra file to relieve the main.cpp for readability. At the very beginning of `main()` I'm then writing `void prizes();` to include the procedure there).
So there's sth like `std::cin >> a_wt;` in the 2nd .cpp file.

amongst other things, I have declared `int a_wt;` in the header file and put this header file in both .cpp files.
when compiling the main.cpp I get the error "*uninitialized local variable 'a_wt' used*".

how can I make the main.cpp file see that it shall be patient and it will be initialized in the 2nd .cpp correctly before it gets used in the `transform`line above? I thought the header file will make sure that both .cpp files will "see" each other.
(the code was normally running when I had all in the main.cpp).

**thank you very much for any help!**

ps: about exporting lots of unimportant code into a 2nd .cpp file; Is there an other way to do this than putting it in a void function of the 2nd file?
some links would be enough, since I'm wiling to learn it by myself and not want to take too much of your time.

Comment: Get rid of the global `int a_wt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do, but consider declaring the variable as `extern int a_wt;` in the header, then define it in one single .cpp file, and make sure you include the header in both. Example

```
// header.h
extern int a_wt;

// file1.cpp
#include "header.h"
int a_wt = 42; // need the definition in one translation unit

// file2.cpp
#include "header.h" 
// file2 has access to a_wt now
```

If you want to initialize the global variable by something more complicated, then instead of making it `extern` you can define it into a function as `static` and use it as the result of that function, like

```
// header.h
int get_a_wt();

// file1.cpp
#include "header.h"
int get_a_wt() 
{
    static int a_wt;
    // initialize it here
    return a_wt;
}

// file2.cpp
#include "header.h"
// use get_a_wt() instead of a_wt
int something = get_a_wt();
```

However, try minimizing the usage of global variables, as they make your code harder to read, less local, and prone to nasty side effects.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. simply said: I had 100  lines of "cin>>"  in my main.cpp asking for stuff. And I've put this block in a new .cpp file (coz of readability in main.cpp). now my main.cpp doesn't want to accept the inputs (from the other .cpp file) telling the mentioned error code above.
I am on it to try your tips. ty so far!

Comment: @CarolineSchuster try the `static` function approach, then think about a change in design so you get rid of the global.

Comment: works now! well.. **1st** I guess it was silly to use a void func. so it seems `cin>>` is useless within a void func... I thought it will still give the value to the main.cpp. and **2nd**: your `int something = get_a_wt(); ` made the difference. I never thought that the value I get needs to be assigned to a new identifier. I was thinking that I can directly use the variable that I received with `cin>>`. seems to be different  for multiple files :o (it also works without `static`)

Comment: @CarolineSchuster It should work with `cin` inside a function, see [here](http://ideone.com/Xxdazh), but you must return the `int` from the function. I used `static` as this will initialize the variable only once, at the first run of the function. This is OK for simple functions that only return their initialized parameter, something like `int get(){static int x = 42; return x;}`. But for more complicated initializations, then non-static is ok.

Comment: since you helped me a lot, I wanted to vote up, but seems I don't have enough reputation :o sorry and thank you again x)